# how to validate a same form in different button click using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

`edit-txt`,`updatePassword` are two buttons in a single form **superAdminDetailsForm** . i want to valide this form in both button click. I wrote form validation on each button click .but it doesn't work. edit-txt button is type of text and update password is type of button

```
    $().ready(function() {$('#edit-txt').on('click', function() {
        $("#superAdminDetailsForm").validate({

                    rules: {
                        superadminEmail:{
                            required:true,
                            email:true
                        },  
                    }, 
                    messages: {
                            superadminEmail:"Please enter your Email id"
                    },
                    submitHandler: function(){
                    var formData =$("#superAdminDetailsForm").serialize();
                        $.ajax({
                            url:'/accounts',
                            type:'post',
                            datatype: 'json',
                            data: formData,
                            success : function(response){
                                if(response == "true"){
                                    window.location='/accounts';
                                } else {
                                     alert("false")
                                }
                            },
                            error: function (request,status, error) {
                            }
                        });
                    return false;
                }
            });

    });


    $('#updatePassword').on('click', function()  {$("#superAdminDetailsForm").validate({

            rules: {
                oldPassword:"required",
                newPassword:"required",
                confirmpassword:{
                    require :"true",
                    equalTo : "#oldPassword"
                } 
            },
             messages: {
                 oldPassword:"Please enter Old Password ",
                 newPassword: "Please enter New Password",
                 confirmpassword:"Retype password is incorrect"
             },
            submitHandler: function(){//to pass all data of a form serial
                 var formData =$("#superAdminDetailsForm").serialize();
                        $.ajax({
                            url:'/changePassword',
                            type:'post',
                            datatype: 'json',
                            data: formData,
                            success : function(response){
                                if(response == "true"){
                                    window.location = '/accounts';
                                } else {
                                    alert("password incorrect");
                                }
                            },
                            error: function (request,status, error) {
                            }
                        });
                    return false;
                }


        });
    });
});
```